# How to get event in another control event?

Tags: asp.net

In my application, i am trying to get button_click event in another button click event, but it is not working.

My code is,

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("hi.....");
}

protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btn1.Click += new EventHandler(this.btn1_Click);
}
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to call the code of btn1_click event.

If this is the case, you simple call it as a method in your btn2_Click.

```
 protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     btn1_Click (sender, e);
 }
```